# Why is XAMPP loading old file?

Tags: php, xampp

I am running my code. I have a javascript file with the actual contents like this:

```
function setDeleteAction(tid, id, img) {

    if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete this image?")) {
        console.log("delete_img.php?tid="+tid+"&id="+id+"&img="+img);

        document.profileForm.action = "delete_img.php?tid="+tid+"&id="+id+"&img="+img;

        document.getElementById("profile-form").submit();
    }
}
```

And I had an older version loaded in my web-directory.

Now that I have my new version of JS included in my code; I have just modified my file and thats it. I dont understand why is XAMPP getting my old file. Please help.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Mozilla.. I have firebug installed.

Comment: Please try with remove cache/cookie from your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a caching related problem. The older version of the script is probably cached by your browser.

Try clearing the cache and reload the page. May be it'll work.

FYI, firefox has a shotcut fot that. `Ctrl + Shift + Delete`